# Pocket Sphinx slow using a grammar

Tags: grammar, cmusphinx

I have been trying to use CMU's Pocket Sphinx to perform speech recognition on an Android tablet.
The tutorial on doing this can be found [here](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/). My problem is that recognition runs really slowly if I use a grammar of any significant size. Using a language model, I can achieve good accuracy and speed, so my *temporary* solution has been to generate a language model from my grammar and use that.
In my configuration, I set `-bestpath = false`. After that, I am at a loss as to how to speed things up.
Clarification: I understand that a large grammar will take a long time to initialize, but I don't think it should take a long time for recognition to run using it.

Is there anyone with experience using Pocket Sphinx and a grammar who can share their experience, configuration, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

We used pocketsphinx on a 1Ghz Android mobile following tutorials available on the net (just do a google search). It was quite quick to startup, but it hung up after you stopped recording for about 10 secs even if you only recorded 2 words. This was using the default "hub4" prerecorded grammer.